# One corner point duplicate and two level full factorial design main effects calculation

Tags: experiment-design, fractional-factorial

I conducted a series of experiments corresponding to a full factorial design with 3 factors and two levels per factor.
I entered the data in a software (minitab, not sure if relevant) the calculation yielded were: no significant main or interaction effects.

Afterwards I conducted a duplicate of one of the corner points experiments and measured the value, I added the data from the duplicate to the software, and things changed, main effects and interactions could be calculated.

Could you please tell me if duplicating one corner point of a FFD is valid and if using the data from the duplicate for effects calculation is valid as well?

Comment: To my understanding, you are sheeting, which makes your results worthless

Comment: @DirkHorsten Can you please explain what "sheeting" is?

Comment: I meant cheating.

Comment: Could you share your code?